# Алгоритм Дейкстры тоже самое что двигаться всегда по кратчайшему пути?

Tags: алгоритм, математика, графы

На [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B) есть растолковка алгоритма Дейкстры в действии.

Судя по финальному просчёту должно получиться движение по красным наименьшим вершинам 0 => 7 => 9 => 11 => 20 => 20

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

НО. Если не использовать алгоритм и не высчитывать вершину и всегда двигаться просто по наименьшему ребру, получается такое же движение 0 => 7 => 9 => 11 => 20 => 20.

Выходит тоже самое движение без использования алгоритма Дейкстры. Зачем тогда нужен этот алгоритм или я чего то не понимаю?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вот вам граф:

```
   1
*-----*
|     |
|1    |1
|     |
|  2  |
O-----*
```

Двигаясь просто "по наименьшему ребру", вы получите расстояние между нижними вершинами - 3, не смотря на то, что прямое ребро между ними короче.